# Adobe AIR system tray drop target

Tags: air

I would like to make a system tray icon from Adobe AIR app a drop target. Is this even possible? Digging hard, but without success so far.

Answer (score 0):

Taking a look at the documentation for `flash.desktop.SystemTrayIcon` it appears that there are no events dispatched for dragging and dropping on the system tray icon. [As per the documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/desktop/SystemTrayIcon.html#eventSummary), only a few mouse events are dispatched when interacting with the system tray icon.